# How to reload GridView based on DropDownList selection dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I'm trying to load/reload a GridView based on the `OnSelectedIndexChanged` event of a `DropDownList`. The ddl has `AutoPostBack` set to true, but still the Grid won't load, unless I encapsulate it within an `UpdatePanel`. But once I do that, my FileUpload control stops working... What would be the best solution for this problem?

**Edit ** Relevant code:

aspx file

```
    <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upProva" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
                <%--user control for data selection--%>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlAula" runat="server" DataTextField="nmAula" DataValueField="idAula"
                    CssClass="medio" Enabled="false" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlAula_OnSelectedIndexChanged">
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
        <asp:GridView ID="gvQuestoes" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CssClass="gv"
            AllowSorting="false" DataKeyNames="idQuestao" OnRowCommand="gvQuestao_RowCommand">
            <Columns>
                <%--(...)--%>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
<asp:Button ID="btnSalvar" runat="server" ToolTip="Salvar" CssClass="botao40 salv40"
                    OnClick="btnSalvar_Click" ValidationGroup="trabalho" />
        <asp:FileUpload ID="fuAnexo" runat="server" CssClass="fileOriginal" />
    </asp:Content>
```

codebehind

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        btnArquivo.OnClientClick = "document.getElementById('" + fuAnexo.ClientID + "').click(); return false;";
        txtAnexo.Attributes.Add("onclick", "document.getElementById('" + fuAnexo.ClientID + "').click(); return false;");
        fuAnexo.Attributes.Add("onchange", "document.getElementById('" + txtAnexo.ClientID + "').value = this.value;");

    }
}

protected void ddlAula_OnSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    gvQuestoes.DataSource = Questao.CarregarPorAula(Int32.Parse(ddlAula.SelectedValue));
    gvQuestoes.DataBind();
}
```

The DataSource/Databinding is correct (I know because I've added a button to the page, and used the same binding code on the Button _Click event and it works).

Comment: can you show your relevant code?

Comment: Hi add a code please. So it may be possible to show you an example.

Comment: You need to rebind the gridview.

Comment: Sure, adding relevant code now.

Comment: can you show `page_load()`??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a fairly simple (though not ideal in all cases) with PostBackTrigger:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upProva" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
                <%--user control for data selection--%>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlAula" runat="server" DataTextField="nmAula" DataValueField="idAula"
                    CssClass="medio" Enabled="false" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlAula_OnSelectedIndexChanged">
                </asp:DropDownList>

        <asp:GridView ID="gvQuestoes" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CssClass="gv"
            AllowSorting="false" DataKeyNames="idQuestao" OnRowCommand="gvQuestao_RowCommand">
            <Columns>
                <%--(...)--%>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
        <asp:FileUpload ID="fuAnexo" runat="server" CssClass="fileOriginal" />
   </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
    <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnSalvar" />    
    </Triggers>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to rebind the gridview in `OnSelectedIndexChanged` event. Something like

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  //Do your processing logic

  gridview1.DataSource = new_modified_datasource;
  gridview1.DataBind();  
}
```

Comment: My code already includes that, but unfortunately it won't work unless I encapsulate the GridView inside the UpdatePanel. Have a look at the code I just posted. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Nowhere in your code do you show how you populate `ddlAula`. So here is my answer: the `Page_Load` you've shown is abbreviated, and actually you are populating `ddlAula` there. Furthermore, you are doing it each time, rather than checking `IsPostBack`. Therefore by the time your eventhandler for `ddlAula` is hit, the list has been reset and the value you selected is no longer selected.

If my answer is correct, you need to add the check in `Page_Load`:

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
    //populate ddlAula
}
```

Comment: No, it's populated somewhere else and I didn't include it because it wasn't necessary. My problem was specifically about the `FileUploader` control not working with asynchronous postback (when inside the `UpdatePanel`. Thanks anyway.